# Catching objects causing SQLite multiple thread access errors

Tags: python, sqlite, pdb

I got this familiar sight when running my unit tests on Python and SQLite:

```
   SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread.
```

The tests run fine, but the errors are still being printed out. I assume SQLite objects somehow leak to the background thread.

Instead of dissecting my code piece by piece, is there a simple a way to

- Put `pdb` breakpoint somewhere and see in which thread which object causes the violation (and thus figure out instantly how it ended up there in the first place).
- Print out the objects (and parents which refer them) somehow with the error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far by looking at the source of of pysqlite, I can say that it is not possible to share connection or cursor objects (see `pysqlite_check_thread` function usage) only.

`pysqlite_check_thread` function raises `ProgrammingError` exception with that message

```
SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread.
```

Some function in your source code catches that exception and prints it.

In order to find places in your source code that call connection methods in other threads, I would suggest to write call wrapper over connection object something like this:

```
# script name: sqllitethread.py
import inspect
import sqlite3
import threading
import thread
from sqlite3 import ProgrammingError


class CallWrapper(object):

    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj
        self.main_thread_id = thread.get_ident()

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if self.main_thread_id != thread.get_ident():
            print "Thread %s requested `%s` attribute from %s" % (thread.get_ident(), name, self.obj)
            for frame in inspect.getouterframes(inspect.currentframe())[1:]:
                if frame[1].endswith('threading.py'):
                    continue
                print "\t", "%s:%s" % (frame[1], frame[2]), frame[3], frame[4][0].strip()
        return getattr(self.obj, name)


conn = CallWrapper(sqlite3.connect('example.db'))
c = conn.cursor()

def worker():
    try:
        conn.execute('.tables')
    except ProgrammingError, e:
        print e

t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
t.start()
t.join()
```

Output example:

```
Thread 140390877370112 requested `execute` attribute from <sqlite3.Connection object at 0x7faf4e659858>
    sqllitethread.py:30 worker conn.execute('.tables')
SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread.The object was created in thread id 140390912665408 and this is thread id 140390877370112
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the comprehensive answer (sorry that bounty had already expired). I'll try this out and see how it plays out - not very straightforward, but didn't expect it to be.